# Static MediaPlayer stops one second after loop for no reason

Tags: android, loops, android-mediaplayer

Today I added a static MediaPlayer to my Activity. 
It is static so I can stop it from outside the class it is written in. 
But for some reason the MediaPlayer stops after the second or third loop without an error in Logcat.
This is my code:

```
public static MediaPlayer player;
public static void SoundPlayer(Context ctx,int raw_id){
    player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, raw_id);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100, 100);
    player.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setLooping after start()

```
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     player.start();
 }
}); 
player.setLooping(true); // Set after start()
```

Comment: So I did this and now there is an IllegalStateExeption on prepareASync(); . When I remove prepareASync it is still not looping.